# PHP: Moving from WAMP server to online server

Tags: phpmyadmin, passwords, localhost, wamp

I have already transferred my mysql database from phpmyadmin to the server and copied my php files as well. I get this error when trying to access my site:

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Please help me with that. Should I transfer my php.ini? should I change the localhost to my web address inside my php files? what else? thanks!

Comment: refer to this thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325115/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password

Comment: I think that you must check your credentials on production server. If your application is on hosted services (not your own), you are certainly not root user.

Answer (score 0):

Once the site is running on the new LIVE server you will have to change your sites database connection details.

The hosting company will normally run a seperate server to hold the MySQL database server and provide you with specific

```
Host 
Userid 
and Password.
```

so that you can connect to it.

Look on the pages that you used to create the database on the Server, it should normally tell you the details there.