# java - mysql connection error 1045 sqlstate 28000

Tags: java, mysql, access-denied

I am trying to connect to mysql database from my java application. I am using Connector J driver. I can connect to mysql from 'cmd' and netbeans but when I try to connect to the database using java code it shows error 1045 sqlstate 28000 Access denied for user 'sayeed'@'localhost'. I've searched various topics like:
[Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081339/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-mysqlerror)
and
[How to connect NetBeans to MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081307/how-to-connect-netbeans-to-mysql-database) but none of them worked for me.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.print("Driver not Found");
}

try {
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqltest", "sayeed", "miracle");
    System.out.printf("okay");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.print(e.getSQLState() + " " + e.getErrorCode());
    System.out.print("\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
}
```

This shows the error:

```
28000 1045
Access denied for user 'sayeed'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

using 'cmd' i can connect to mysql
[accessing database from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N5hi.png)
and i can connect to the database using netbeans new connection wizard.
[connecting to database from netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGZ2p.png)

Note: I have granted all privileges to 'sayeed'
my user table in mysql database shows (all privileges for sayeed)

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You'll be better off if you print the stack trace in your catch blocks rather than selectively choosing messages.  Look at this question and scroll down to the 3rd answer by @Doug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325115/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password

Comment: my root password is blank

Comment: You aren't using the root password to log in via Java (and you shouldn't under any circumstance).   I see username "sayeed" and password "miracle".  That's a different user from root.  Did you GRANT that user access?  sayeed != root.

Comment: @duffymo, yes i have granted all privileges for database sqltest to sayeed.In fact, 'sayeed' has all the privileges 'root' has (global and for 'sqltest').

Comment: @duffymo, sayeed@localhost